# Android Studio build tools error everytime i open a project

Tags: android, android-studio

My android studio shows this error "Failed to find Build Tools revision 28.0.3" everytime i open a project, like I have to download this 55MB file just to sync right and open each project. I already did it in one of the projects and it works, but since I dont have stable internet connection, it's a pain in the ass to download 55MB everytime I open a project. I honestly dont think this is normal. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update to Android Studio 3.6 ? This version has a better download management and it is done for unstable internet connection. Each time you open a new project you need to sync your gradle. You can also use a new version of Build Tools `29.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line and sync it

```
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
```

Comment: i dont see a line like this in my build.gradle